# "The import java.awt cannot be resolved" and " ***** cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded a Java project that I want to study and learn some things from. When I downloaded it on another computer it worked great, but when I try it on my computer, nearly every declaration and import is given the error message "***** cannot be resolved to a type" or "The import java.awt cannot be resolved".

I did some research on this site and found that it might have to do with not having the latest Java installed. I checked mine, and I have JavaSE-1.7 (unbound). So I have the latest version but it's (unbound)?

Can this be the problem? And what does (unbound) mean?

**I'm using Eclipse  3.3.2**

UPDATE: I just found this error message at the top of the Properties window: **org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7**. What does this mean?

Comment: are the necessary jars in your build path?

Comment: Does the same code work ok in another IDE?

Comment: I don't know. I've only Eclipse

Comment: try to clean the project or restart Eclipse.

Comment: it should be `import java.awt.*;`

Comment: Click **Project->Properties->Java Build Path** and make sure you see the standard Java Library.

Comment: Maybe you have configured it as an Android project? Android uses the Java syntax BUT IT IS NOT JAVA.

Comment: ctrl+shift+O will resolve all your imports. Please try

Comment: @TimurAykutYıldırım I have the JRE System Library[JavaSE-1.7](unbound)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This occurs because project has dependency on library of J2SE 1.7 but it cannot find JRE at that location in your machine.

**Project->Properties->Java Build Path**

Or Add a new JRE in eclipse using **Window>Preferences>Java>Installed JRE** and locate the path of the JRE folder in your machine. and then replace the dependency of your project with the new JRE you installed in eclipse.

**UPDATE**
[UNBOUND JRE in Hello World](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542051/eclipse-frustration-with-java-1-7-unbound-library)

Comment: Window>Preferences>Java>Installed JRE ?? I don't see "Installed JRE" where you say it is....

Comment: click Add ---> Standard VM -----> JRE Home (Directory where JRE is installed in your machine) ----> Finish.

Comment: I don't see any Add button either. This is what the Preferences>Java window shows: http://imgur.com/T4znR

Comment: @Imray expand the little arrow to the left of "Java" in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for some... it did for me:

1. Hover over "java.awt" in your code, and under **quick fixes available**, select **Fix Project Setup**.
2. Pop-up displays saying "*The following proposals have been found...*"  and
   "*Add Library JRE System Library[JavaSE-1.7] to build path*" is selected.
3. Select Ok.

Answer (score -1):

Problem  occurs because project has dependency on library of java 1.7 but it cannot find JRE at  specified  location in your machine.

Project->Properties->Java Build Path

Or Add a new JRE in eclipse using Window>Preferences>Java>Installed JRE and locate the path of the JRE folder in your machine. and then replace the dependency of your project with the new JRE you installed in eclipse. if teher is No JRE and click on add jre tab and provide the directory location of the Jre and add that.