# Java AWT package "not accessible" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try and import the AWT package in eclipse by doing "import java.awt.*;" at the beginning of my code it comes up with an error that "The package java.awt is not accessible." java.util seems to work fine, but the awt package doesn't. I'm not sure what I need to do to make it "accessible".

Comment: rebuild the project, or clean the project or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705087/the-import-java-awt-cannot-be-resolved-and-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-typ)

Comment: Hmm, none of that seems to work

Comment: Finally got it to work by adding "requires java.desktop;" into "module-info.java". More information can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503140/the-import-java-awt-cannot-be-resolved/51504409

Comment: Late here, but just wanted to say that adding the "requires java.desktop" in "module-info.java" worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can fix it by following the following steps:

Go to: Project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add Library -> Execution Environment

Select the drop down list and then choose "javaSE-1.7"

That solved the problem for me!

Comment: That's a terrible solution for, especially as it was posted in 2020. That's not solving the problem that's avoiding it all together. Also, this will only work for those who still have JavaSE-1.7.