# How do I fix this illegal access error I am getting when running my code in Eclipse?

Tags: java

I've just started coding in Java using Eclipse and this is the code that is causing the error:

```
package notes;

import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
/**
 * 
 */
public class practice {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50);
                System.out.println(box1.width);
        
    }
}
```

After running this, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class notes.practice (in module notes) cannot access class java.awt.Rectangle (in module java.desktop) because module notes does not read module java.desktop
    at notes/notes.practice.main(practice.java:18)
```

I was running into a lot of errors before this such as "error occurred during initialization of boot layer" and "#include errors detected. Update your include path." and fixed those by adding libraries to the build path. However, I can't seem to find the reason for this error. The libraries I added were JavaSE-11 and CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0.

Comment: The error indicates you have a `module-info.java` file (i.e., your code is modular) but you're missing a `requires java.desktop;` directive. I'm surprised it compiles in the first place (though maybe that has to do with ECJ vs javac). Anyway, try adding that aforementioned requires directive, or making your code non-modular by deleting the `module-info` file.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to rebuild the project or clean it?

You can also follow below two links which had similar issue:

[Java AWT package "not accessible" in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149911/java-awt-package-not-accessible-in-eclipse)

[The import java.awt cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503140/the-import-java-awt-cannot-be-resolved)