# "Serializable cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization

I'm using Eclipse to create a simple project. 
I'm trying to implement Serializable in my Java class, but Eclipse is not recognizing it saying "Serializable cannot be resolved to a type" and offering me to create an inteface called Serializable.

```
public class Location implements Serializable {
```

Isn't Serializable supposed to be a built in interface? How do I get it to work?

Comment: There is no "built in interface" but there are automatic imports (`java.lang`). `Serializable` is in `java.io`, which is _not_ among the automatic imports? See answer from @Reimeus

Answer (score 7):

You need to import it from the `java.io` package:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
```

Comment: So the other user who deleted his answer maybe was right. I suggest him/her to undelete.

Comment: Strange....`java.io` is one of the core packages in Java, i.e. it's not an external library.

Comment: @gd1, I undeleted my answer.

Comment: @Imray can you restart Eclipse and see if it makes any difference? Failing that I'd say to install the latest JDK and install for Eclipse.

Comment: @Imray After adding the import statement, what is the exact error you receive?

Comment: I was looking at my library, and I noticed that my it says "[unbound]" next to it. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Your JDK might be ok, in which case you can simply re-install it in Eclipse - [Instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542051/eclipse-frustration-with-java-1-7-unbound-library). Otherwise I'd go for a new download.

Answer (score 3):

You have to `import java.io.Serializable`.

If you click the "error icon" in Eclipse, at the left of the offending line, Eclipse can do it for you. Or just press `Ctrl+Shift+O`.

Comment: Would you paste the whole class?

Comment: So far it's just that one line

Comment: @MouseEvent I know, but Eclipse is highlight the "java.io" part and telling me it can't resolve it to a type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) is an interface. Perhaps you've failed to configure your build path correctly?

Comment: For an invalid CP there would likely be many more problems O.o

Comment: @pst, "*it saying "Serializable cannot be resolved to a type" and offering me to create an inteface called Serializable*"..you would think OP would recognize that Eclipse would give you the option to import the interface as well..

Comment: You're very trusting of posters :-)

Comment: @pst, Yeah..I'll remove my answer.

Comment: No, don't do that. It's not inherently wrong - I up-voted it - and I don't see why this couldn't be the problem, even if I suspect otherwise.

Comment: Yes I believe that is it. For some reason when I go to Properties and look at my build path, it says "[unbounded]".

Answer (score 0):

you have just to right click on your project => buildpath => jre => and you specify the right jre and it will gives you the possibility of importing java.io.Serialisable;