# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error - Oracle Java tutorial

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I'm taking this oracle java tutorial and trying to use this code in Eclipse. I've been able to just create new classes and copy the code into the class. I can't seem to use this code in Eclipse. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/StringSwitchDemo.java

I keep getting Class not found errors. I named the class correctly.

Here's a screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/r58wX.jpg

I don't understand what I need to change to allow the code to run.

```
public class StringSwitchDemo {

    public static int getMonthNumber(String month) {

        int monthNumber = 0;

        if (month == null) {
            return monthNumber;
        }

        switch (month.toLowerCase()) {
            case "january":
                monthNumber = 1;
                break;
            case "february":
                monthNumber = 2;
                break;
            case "march":
                monthNumber = 3;
                break;
            case "april":
                monthNumber = 4;
                break;
            case "may":
                monthNumber = 5;
                break;
            case "june":
                monthNumber = 6;
                break;
            case "july":
                monthNumber = 7;
                break;
            case "august":
                monthNumber = 8;
                break;
            case "september":
                monthNumber = 9;
                break;
            case "october":
                monthNumber = 10;
                break;
            case "november":
                monthNumber = 11;
                break;
            case "december":
                monthNumber = 12;
                break;
            default: 
                monthNumber = 0;
                break;
        }

        return monthNumber;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String month = "August";

        int returnedMonthNumber =
            StringSwitchDemo.getMonthNumber(month);

        if (returnedMonthNumber == 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid month");
        } else {
            System.out.println(returnedMonthNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

I got this errors in my IDE (Eclipse)

[image]

Comment: Just by any mean, do you have declared some class with name `String` among your classes?

Comment: Don't give screenshots.  Copy/paste your code/messages into your question, taking care to indent 4 spaces (or use the `{}` button above the edit window to do so) so that they're formatted as "code".

Comment: No. You can see in the screenshot. No classes named String. All my practice classes before this have run fine.

Comment: Have you got something on the line above what the screen shot shows?  Or is `public class StringSwitchDemo {` the first line of your file?

Comment: public class StringSwitchDemo is the first line of the file.

Comment: OK, do you have the right number of `}` characters at the bottom?

Comment: Your screenshot show several compile errors in your code.  What do you see in the `problems` view?

Comment: Please provide the complete code of your class here in your question (not as a comment).

Comment: Yes, no compilation errors. http://imgur.com/kcc0hvE

Comment: Look like you have a Problem in your Project. Look at the Problems tab what can you see there?

Comment: I'll post the code but its exactly the same as the code provided by the oracle tutorial.

Comment: Here's my Problems tab. What can I do to fix this? I never had this problem with my other Java exercises. http://i.imgur.com/KwaLv5n.png

Comment: In your first screen dump, there were four red stripes down the right hand side, next to the scrollbar.  In your second screen dump, they weren't there.  At what point did they disappear?

Comment: From your last screenshot, looks like your Eclipse doesn't have the JDK 7 configured or that your project lost that configuration.

Comment: Do you have the JDK installed?

Comment: Sorry guys I've been trying sooo many things for the past hour. I don't know what happened to the four red stripes.

Comment: Whoops, and by "four" I mean "six".  I'll go back to kindergarten and learn to count.

Comment: can you check this ?? right-click project -> Properties  -> Java Build Path -> libraries  Does it show the jre system library?

Comment: Here's my Java Build Path properties. http://imgur.com/ZhEWEMf

Comment: if you see the screenshot it shows unbound in the brackets after your jre. May be this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542051/eclipse-frustration-with-java-1-7-unbound-library

Comment: goto > windows > preferences > java > installed_jre > select jdk 7 > check path is correct and jdk is actually exist on that path

Comment: Could someone help me with this sentence? "It's worth adding that on the preference pane for "Installed JREs", you can just hit the "Search" button to automatically locate JDK 7, if it is installed." Where is the preference pane?

Comment: it just says that if you go to the windows -> preferences -> java -> installed jre, on the right hand side you should see a search button, you can select your java installation directory by browsing through your system folders

Comment: Added jre7. Thanks rahul! http://i.imgur.com/kIq9LTK.png

Comment: But does it work now, Stacy?

Comment: Yes, David. Code works! No errors.