# Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [OSGi/Minimum-1.2]'

Tags: java

hi experts i am new to java programming.

I have installed an ADT bundle and it came with eclipse Version: 1.4.1.v20120912-144938-8R7xFOXFLWUl7PpNBh_HIGkb4  , Build id: M20130204-1200
The JDK version installed is "1.8_0_11".

I build simple android apps it worked well, but for a simple java project it shows me following errors :

Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [OSGi/Minimum-1.2]' in project. 
I tried all the solutions provided above, but it did not work. Could please help me to fix it.

Comment: _I tried all the solutions provided above, but it did not work._ What solutions are you talking about?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542051/eclipse-frustration-with-java-1-7-unbound-library